# Assign value from eval()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, eval

Here is my code currently (with unnecessary elements removed obviously):

```
var foo = new Array();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        foo[0] = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        // After this point, I want to be able to reference 
        // foo[0].bar1
        // and 
        // foo[0].bar2()
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", "myfunc.js", true);
xhr.send();
```

This is the content of `myfunc.js`, but it's not working.

```
function() {
    this.bar1 = "Hello World";
    this.bar2 = function()
    {
        console.log("this is bar2");
    };
}
```

This works, but it's assigning `bar` and `bar2` to `foo` rather than `foo[0]`. How can I ensure that it assigns them to `foo[0]`?

Comment: I'd seriously rethink the structure of your program. Pass data about with Ajax, not code.

Comment: It's for a game, objects are loaded from the server based on what's needed at the time and then stored into a single array for easy reference.

Comment: Sounds like you should pass something like `{ "what": "type of object", "data": { ... } }` instead, and then `arr.push(new GAME.THINGS[response.what](response.data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using JSON (as Quentin suggested) instead of defining a self modifying function. 
My resulting `myfunc.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "bar1": "Hello World",
    "bar2": function()
    {
        console.log("this is bar2");
    }
}
```

As for the structure, I'm not overly concerned about it. It's running on LAN only and is meant to demonstrate an idea I had about WebGL rather than being a practical, fully finished game.

Answer (score 0):

`myfunc.js` contains an anonymous JavaScript class (= anonymous function), which is not yet instantiated. Therefore, in your main script, `eval()` returns just that class. `foo[0]` now can be used to instantiate objects from that class; it's something like the class name.

My point is that you're trying to get properties from a class (and not from an object), which of course doesn't work. So you basically have two options to solve the problem:

1. Create an instance of the anonymous class returned by `eval()`:

   ```
   foo[0] = new (eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"));
   console.log(foo[0].bar1);
   ```
2. Return a (singleton) object instead of a class from `myfunc.js`:

   ```
   new function() {
       this.bar1 = "Hello World";
   }
   ```

Btw, in my opinion, Quentin has a good point in saying you should rethink the structure of your program...